# Exclude Parent entire node if child has some specific string

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have the following XML

```
<root>
<Package1>
<Name> Test </Name>
<Sales_Channel ID=123>
<Name>Online</Name>
</Sales_Channel>
<Sales_Channel ID=234>
<Name>Direct</Name>
</Sales_Channel>
</Package1>
<Package2>
<Name> Test </Name>
<Sales_Channel ID=234>
<Name>Direct</Name>
</Sales_Channel>
</Package2>
<Package3>
<Name> Test </Name>
<Sales_Channel ID=123>
<Name>Online</Name>
</Sales_Channel>
</Package3>
</root>
```

I would like to exclude those packages which is tagged with only

```
<Sales_Channel ID=123>
<Name>Online</Name>
</Sales_Channel>
```

So my final output should look like below:

```
<root>
<Package1>
<Name> Test </Name>
<Sales_Channel ID=123>
<Name>Online</Name>
</Sales_Channel>
<Sales_Channel ID=234>
<Name>Direct</Name>
</Sales_Channel>
</Package1>
<Package2>
<Name> Test </Name>
<Sales_Channel ID=234>
<Name>Direct</Name>
</Sales_Channel>
</Package2>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you.  It works in Microsoft 1.0.  I did have to add quotes around your ID values to get it to work there.

```
  <!-- Suppress. -->
  <xsl:template match="*[contains(local-name(), 'Package') and .//Sales_Channel[@ID='123'] and not(.//Sales_Channel[@ID!='123'])]"/>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```